# Is it possible to open Microsoft Edge from a page rendered in Internet Explorer via just HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

Windows 10 ships with both modern Microsoft Edge browser, and the legacy Internet Explorer 11.

Based on analytics, I suspect some of my Windows 10 users use IE11 and are perhaps not aware of having Edge browser.

Is it possible to create a link in HTML which opens the website in Edge, if the user is on IE11 on Win10?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible to open a URL in Edge Spartan thanks to `microsoft-edge:` protocol. This works in any browser on Windows 10. For example:

```
<a href="microsoft-edge:https://www.cnn.com">CNN</a>
```

***Note however that this does not (yet?) work with Edge Chromium.***

Checking if browser is IE11 on Windows 10 can be done for example as follows:

```
if (document.documentMode === 11 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Windows NT 10.0') > -1) {
    ...
}
```

If you want to create an Edge link to the current page (without hardcoding), you can do it with JavaScript:

```
myAnchor.href = 'microsoft-edge:' + document.URL;
```

Demo: https://jg-testpage.github.io/ie11/open-in-edge.html?foo=bar&baz=quux

Comment: I can see that you had posted the answer for your own question. I suggest you to mark that solution as an accepted answer for this thread after 24 hrs may help other community members in future who will have similar kind of question. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks, this solution does solve my problem.