# Need to Open a Hyperlink in Edge (issues)

Tags: html, hyperlink, attributes, anchor

I am creating a website and need to have a specific link open with the Edge browser. (Company designed software to only work with Edge as its easier for SSO, not compatible with Firefox or Chrome)

I created an anchor tag with the microsoft-edge parameter and the link will open up fine when using other browsers like Firefox (a popup will force the user to select edge) but when actually using edge the link does not do anything. Upon inspecting element the anchor tag is not even rendered in the DOM.

The following is an example of how i used the anchor.

```
<a href="microsoft-edge:https://google.com> Click Here </a>
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Well, to start, your anchor, `<a href="microsoft-edge:https://google.com>` is missing a `"` to close the value of the href attribute. The working code appears in the following snippet:

```html
<a href="microsoft-edge:https://google.com"> Click Here </a>
```

However, this only explains the final issue you mention :

> ...the anchor tag is not even rendered in the DOM

*(I assume you got tangled up in your troubleshooting steps)*

**The actual problem is** that Microsoft Edge doesn't support the `microsoft-edge:` protocol. I haven't found a published source for this, but I have found a reference to this issue (and a javascript-based workaround) in the SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53765993/2540235